# How to fix android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making an application in Android Studio that will allow a user to add items to a shopping list. I am having trouble implementing the add function for the database. I want a user to be able to type an item name and quantity into two edit text boxes, and these information are then stored in my database. I used [these](http://mobilesiri.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-using-android-studio/) [tutorials](http://www.androidauthority.com/use-sqlite-store-data-app-599743/) when setting up the database and trying to implement the add functionality.

Currently, when I run the code, it will display the app on my device; but when I click a button to go to the page represented by this activity, I get this error and the app crashes:

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence

Here is my code in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    id = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.KEY_ID, 0);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    EditText addAnItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
    EditText addQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_quantity);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    addAnItem.setText((CharSequence)addAnItem);
    addAnItem.setFocusable(false);
    addAnItem.setClickable(false);
    addQuantity.setText((CharSequence)addQuantity);
    addQuantity.setFocusable(false);
    addQuantity.setClickable(false);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    String itemName = addAnItem.getText().toString();
    String itemQuantity = addQuantity.getText().toString();
    db.addItem(new Item(id, itemName, itemQuantity));
}
```

The database add function:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, item.getItemName());
    values.put(KEY_QUANTITY, item.getItemQuantity());
    db.insert(TABLE_LITEMS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

And the item class:

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemQuantity;

    public Item(){
    }

    public Item(int id,String itemName,String itemQuantity){
        this.id=id;
        this.itemName=itemName;
        this.itemQuantity=itemQuantity;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName){
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public void setItemQuantity(String itemQuantity){
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getItemName(){
        return itemName;
    }

    public String getItemQuantity(){
        return itemQuantity;
    }
}
```

I used the CharSequence cast in the activity because otherwise it gives me

> cannot resolve method setText(android.widget.EditText)

I couldn't find another way to resolve that error.

What modifications can I make to the code in order to add a user supplied item to my database?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` Use

```
   addAnItem.setText(addAnItem..getText().toString());
   addQuantity.setText(addQuantity.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
  addAnItem.setText((CharSequence)addAnItem);
  addQuantity.setText((CharSequence)addQuantity);
```

Comment: Okay now I can open the page but my EditText won't show up for some reason.

Comment: I don't really understands what you are trying to implement here! but this is the way to get a text from an `edittext`

Answer (score 0):

EditText is a view object while setText method takes String or CharSequence.
You cannot set text to view object, it doesn't make sense. What you want is

```
String text = addAnItem.getText().toString();
addAnItem.setText(text);
```

But I still don't understand what your code is supposed to do, you are setting text of a view to itself?

Comment: I followed a tutorial, this is the first thing I've ever done in Android Studio I'm not sure how it all works yet.